# Frequent Laptop Freezing and Unresponsiveness When Using Multiple Browsers - Seeking Help

Tags: laptop, thinkpad

I own a Lenovo ThinkPad E15 Gen 3 laptop running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, which I purchased around a year ago. Lately, I've been encountering a recurring issue that has become quite bothersome. While using my laptop, it frequently pauses and becomes unresponsive, necessitating a forced shutdown by holding down the power button. After restarting, the laptop works fine again.

This problem seems to manifest particularly when I have two browsers (Chrome and Firefox) open simultaneously, or when I have multiple tabs open in my default browser, Firefox. Despite having a limited number of software applications installed, I'm puzzled by the regularity of these freezes.

I'm reaching out to this forum to seek advice and potential solutions for this frustrating problem. Has anyone else experienced a similar issue on Ubuntu or any other operating system? If so, could you kindly share any insights or recommendations to help me address this problem? Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the results of the terminal command `free`. Do you have swap space?